# Azure FHIR Proxy using Postman - 401 You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I have set up an instance of Azure FHIR with an Azure FHIR proxy using this tutorial:

https://github.com/microsoft/health-architectures/tree/master/FHIR/FHIRProxy##configuration

I am unable to call the proxy without getting the following error message:

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

[image: Headers]

I have created a token successfully using the following tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/access-fhir-postman-tutorial

I have created an app service principal in Azure with the permissions to access the FHIR proxy:

```
https://func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net
```

I am generating the token using the following in postman:

**Auth URL:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/e34c8e67-182a-4085-9dc0-39a38dddea12/oauth2/authorize/?resource=https://func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net

**Access Token URL:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/e34c8e67-182a-4085-9dc0-39a38dddea12/oauth2/token

**Client ID:**  4d138742-44c0-42cb-9878-8647a1d2ef17

**Client Secret:** Well..that's a secret!

**Scope:** openid profile

**State:** 12345

[image: Postman auth token setup]

Postman returns 3 tokens: Access_token, Refresh_token, Id_token.

I have tried each token and all return the same 401 error.

ID token JWT looks like this:

[image: JWT]

I have tried calling the FHIR proxy API's, due to the tutorial I am not 100% which are the correct URLs:

https://func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net/api/fhirproxy/Patient

https://fhir-test-apis.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient/

None of this works, I just keep getting the same error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Should I be calling the FHIR proxy API using the token? If so, why is the API not letting me in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. I found that the resource ID was needed in the auth URL:

[image: Access Token URL]

This can be obtained from Enterprise Applications:

[image: Getting the resource ID from enterprise applications]

Also, creating two separate app registrations:

[image: Two separate app registrations]

Answer (score 0):

The link ending with ".../api/fhirproxy/Patient" is correct for the proxy deployment.

I'd suggest that you do a quick test that you can access the FHIR API without the proxy. You can use the existing deployment and follow instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/access-fhir-postman-tutorial.

Once you get that working, test the FHIR API with the proxy. You can start with the proxy that has the its security disabled (The FHIR api still requires security and you cannot disable it). Once you get that working, you can enable the proxy's security.

Since the proxy is a web app acting as a proxy, you will need two sets of credentials, one set for the FHIR api itself, which you specify in the proxy app, and one set for the proxy web app, which you specify in your client app, e.g. Postman or curl.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is actually very simple, you are using the wrong `scope`.

Usually the 401 error means that the audience of your token does not match your api. When you use the token to call the api, you will receive a 401 unauthorized error. The access token is issued based on the audience, so you must Make sure to set the `scope` to your api when you request the token. Of course you can also parse the token, check the `aud` claim, and make sure it is the api you want to call.

Therefore, according to your requirements, try to change the `scope` to: `https://func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net/.default`

By the way, if you want to call api, you should use access token instead of refresh token and id token.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the scope, it didn't work

Comment: @Funky  Which api are you calling?

Comment: I am able to call the FHIR API through postman using the auth token. However when doing the same using the proxy it will return a 401 unauthorised. This is the proxy: https://func-fhir-proxy-2.azurewebsites.net/api/fhirproxy/Patient. Full information is shown in the post